# How to repeat a function in Python (complete beginner - first lines of code ever)

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I have the following code which I have to build upon (i.e. it can't be written a different way). I know there are other better ways of achieving the end result, but I want to use this code and then repeat it to make a list.

```
from random import choice
number_list = range(1,1001)  # Creates a list from 1 to 1000
random_from_list = choice(number_list)  # Chooses a random number from the list
```

I want to now repeat the choice function above 100 times, then print that list of 100 random numbers that I have chosen from my list of 1000 numbers. I have read up on "for" loops but I can't see how to apply it here.

Comment: `for _ in range(100): print(".")` will print 100 lines containing "."
The `_` is a variable name that we don't care about.

Comment: I just tried this but got 100 lines of "." like you said. I don't see how it incorporates the above code. Can you please tell me how I would get the 100 random numbers from my list using this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to build up your list you could just print them one at a time:

```
for _ in range(100):
    print(choice(number_list))
```

If you want to build your list first you can use a "list comprehension":

```
choices = [choice(number_list) for _ in range(100)]
print(choices)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(100):
    print(choice(number_list))
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I previously tried 

for _ in range(100): print random_from_list

But that just printed the same random number 100 times. If random_from_list = choice(number_list), why would

for _ in range(100): print choice(number_list)

work and

for _ in range(100): print random_number_list

not work?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, I tried to type the code on separate lines but it just squeezed it all together when I pressed enter.

Comment: Yeah, that's hard to read. I know you can use backticks (right below the tilda ~) to set code blocks. Might help. Anyway, honestly, I didn't even know about `for _ in range...`. Learned something new

Comment: Your variable has already been assigned a random number, it will not be randomized again if you don't tell it to.

Comment: That makes sense. One last question, if I wanted to save that list instead of printing it i.e. assign it to a variable, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Just like Moberg has in his answer: `choices = [choice(number_list) for _ in range(100)]`